# Unable to delete feature class from file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase, feature-class, delete

I am trying delete feature class which is corrupted from file geodatabase but its throwing error

> Failed to delete selected object(s).
> The item does not have a definition. The XML being loaded could not be parsed.[physical name:my feature class name]
> Xml Parsing failed.
> Reason:An invalid character was found in text content.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your file geodatabase has a corrupted feature class that prevents you deleting it then you could try creating a new file geodatabase and copying everything except for that feature class into it.